# How to find potential points of NullReferenceException in a static code analyzer utility?

Tags: c#, reflection, code-analysis, software-quality

We're developing a static code analysis tool that aims at improving code via some hints.

We want to find places where developer has forgotten to check nullability of a variable or property or method return and has accessed the members via Dot Notation, because it might encounter NullReferenceException.

For example this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var human = new Human();
        if (human.Name.Length > 10)
        {
            // Jeez! you have a long name;
        }
    }
}

public class Human
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

We use Mono.Cecil and we find the body of all methods of all types in a given assembly, and for each method body we find the Instructions of it, and then we check for Callvirt operations. Yet that doesn't support this example:

```
class Program
{
    static string name;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (name.Length > 10)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

How can we find all of the accesses to members (variable, field, property, method) of a given nullable type?

**Update:**
In fact we're searching for OpCodes which represent **member access** for a given variable in IL. Is this possible?

Comment: You want to create a tool that does static code analysis using reflection, *which is no small feat*, but have a basic question on how to use reflection? I think you are putting the cart before the horse on this one. I recommend you first learn all about reflection. Then you will need to learn about how to destruct a method so your code can find cases like the above (that is the harder part). Oh yeah, and after that you will have to notify the user somehow (not sure if this is inline or via a console output). By the way there are tools out there that do a lot of this stuff already.

Comment: A tool like https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper will let you know (inline) if there is a possibility of a NullReferenceException, amongst other things.

Comment: @Igor We already have develped a code analysis/quality based on *TFS* using *Check-in Policies*. Currently, it checks more than 180 rules we have defined to improve the quality of multiple huge code-bases that are getting developed by about 15 developers.
This question is about a new rule we want to add —Null checking should be there whenever required, to prevent NullReferenceException.

Comment: We develop a static code analyzer PVS-Studio  (C++, C#): http://www.viva64.com/en/pvs-studio/ That's why I would like to give an alternative answer. Is there a point in making an analyzer for some internal tasks? Most likely it will be something not very comfortable and additionally it would distract your developers from their main tasks. I suggest redirecting this task to somebody. To us for example :) We make custom diagnostics as well.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`NullReferenceException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.nullreferenceexception) helpfully documents the following:

> The following Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) instructions
>   throw `NullReferenceException`: `callvirt`, `cpblk`, `cpobj`,
>   `initblk`, `ldelem.<type>`, `ldelema`, `ldfld`, `ldflda`,
>   `ldind.<type>`, `ldlen`, `stelem.<type>`, `stfld`, `stind.<type>`,
>   `throw`, and `unbox`.

These break down to the following:

- Array access: `ldelem`, `ldelema`, `ldlen`, `stelem`. The array reference must not be `null`.
- Non-array member access: `ldfld`, `ldflda`, `stfld`. The object reference must not be `null`.
- Method access: `callvirt`. The object reference must not be `null`. Property access is also method access, since it's calling the property getter/setter.
- Pointer/reference access: `cpblk`, `cpobj`, `initblk`, `ldind`, `stind`. The pointer/reference must not be `null`. In verified managed code, these opcodes are not typically used in a context where their arguments could be `null`.
- Throwing an exception: `throw`. The exception reference must not be `null`.
- Unboxing: `unbox`. The object reference must not be `null`.

Tracing the opcode arguments back to variables/fields is another question altogether. This can be arbitrarily complicated since the opcodes only care about what's on the stack, not where it came from. In some cases you may be dealing with expressions (`a[0].SomeMethod().FieldAccess`, where any of `a`, `a[0]` and `a[0].SomeMethod()` could be `null` when they're not supposed to be).

You are better off not checking this on the IL level, but using [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) to provide you with analysis on the language level. Producing high quality feedback is much simpler with access to the source.

Even then, be aware that high quality static analysis for nullability isn't easy. You can certainly write an analyzer that will happily warn at every possible case where the programmer *may* have forgotten to check, but an analyzer like that becomes almost useless if the programmer is forced to insert tons of superfluous checks for references that are *obviously* never `null`. If you tie this to a TFS check-in policy, be prepared to receive death threats from both developers and managers who want to know why productivity has taken a nosedive.

There's a reason existing tools like Resharper add a lot of [attributes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Code_Analysis__Value_Analysis.html) for controlling the analysis, and there's a [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5032) up to add nullability checking to C# itself. Know what you're getting into before reinventing the wheel.